# Lines and raster with R

Tags: raster, r

I have the following raster (shp file using `readORG`):

```
dput(summary_grid)
structure(list(class = structure("SpatialPolygonsDataFrame", package = "sp"), 
    bbox = structure(c(4346000, 3819000, 4445000, 3867000), .Dim = c(2L, 
    2L), .Dimnames = list(c("x", "y"), c("min", "max"))), is.projected = TRUE, 
    proj4string = "+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs", 
    data = structure(c("Min.   :0  ", "1st Qu.:0  ", "Median :0  ", 
    "Mean   :0  ", "3rd Qu.:0  ", "Max.   :0  "), .Dim = c(6L, 
    1L), .Dimnames = list(c("", "", "", "", "", ""), "      Id"), class = "table")), .Names = c("class", 
"bbox", "is.projected", "proj4string", "data"), class = "summary.Spatial")
```

as well as the shp file containing lines:

```
dput(summary_lines)
structure(list(class = structure("SpatialLinesDataFrame", package = "sp"), 
    bbox = structure(c(4329488.96922647, 3429159.10800761, 4998503.48859431, 
    4055688.10547651), .Dim = c(2L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(c("x", 
    "y"), c("min", "max"))), is.projected = TRUE, proj4string = "+proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs", 
    data = structure(c("Min.   :0  ", "1st Qu.:0  ", "Median :0  ", 
    "Mean   :0  ", "3rd Qu.:0  ", "Max.   :0  ", "Min.   :  448  ", 
    "1st Qu.:13229  ", "Median :28235  ", "Mean   :27205  ", 
    "3rd Qu.:40724  ", "Max.   :50608  ", "Min.   :  485  ", 
    "1st Qu.:13731  ", "Median :29399  ", "Mean   :28635  ", 
    "3rd Qu.:43159  ", "Max.   :53607  ", "Min.   :6519754  ", 
    "1st Qu.:8741416  ", "Median :9167928  ", "Mean   :8894830  ", 
    "3rd Qu.:9414708  ", "Max.   :9762259  ", "Fishing:121  ", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Dim = c(6L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(c("", 
    "", "", "", "", ""), c("      Id", "   trip_id", "  new_tr_id", 
    "     species", "  HELCOM_Gro")), class = "table")), .Names = c("class", 
"bbox", "is.projected", "proj4string", "data"), class = "summary.Spatial")
```

In this shp file with the lines, each lines has a unique identification number called new_tr_id.

My goal is to create a raster file with the number if lines crossing each cell. A line (so the same new_tr_id) can cross the same cell X times, it would be counted X times. I added the figure below as example:

[image: In red are the values for each cell. I added the new_tr_id for each line to understand the counting method. For example in the cell surrounded with the blue color, the value is 2 because the lines with the new_tr_id 3 is crossing 2 times]

I have some interesting discussions using the package `raster` but I still can not find a proper answer to this issue.

Some news: I tried the method described by @Spacedman below but it is cutting the lines crossing together:
[image]

I don´t have the same result as @Spacedman but I am not that far anymore :)

Comment: "*A line (so the same new_tr_id) can cross the same cell X times, it would be counted X times.*" Can you upload a figure showing that?

Comment: @aldo_tapia, just did it!

Comment: I think this task could be achieved converting raster to polygons using `new_tr_id` as value field... R interprets rasters as matrices, so could be difficult to do (and I don't know how to do it)

Comment: rasterize(lines, grid, fun = "count") will do it but you'll need a raster version of your grid, something like rasterFromXYZ(coordinates(summary_grid))

Comment: Thanks @mdsumner. So ´rasterFromXYZ()´ is changing the shape file into raster version, right?

Comment: Thanks @mdsummer but it seems that `rasterize()` is not counting twice the same line, for example the case highlighted in blue on the figure in my first message.

Comment: Your dumped objects above are of class "summary.Spatial" - any chance we can get actual sample Spatial data without having to create it ourselves? I think the solution will involve doing an intersection.

Comment: Ah I missed the extra crossings part.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a method using `sf` packages. So install `sf` and `lwgeom` and `dplyr` first.

`polys` is read from a polygon shapefile using `polys = st_read("polys.shp")` - `lines` is read from a line shapefile using `lines=st_read("lines.shp")`/

My lines has a unique `FID` field and my polygons have a unique `id` field.

First compute the intersection:

```
> pli = st_intersection(polys,lines)
```

Each row of this has the `id` and `FID` field of the relevant polygon and line. But in the cases where multiple line segments from the same line appear twice or more in the polygon return as `MULTILINESTRING` segments. For these we need to count the number of LINESTRING segments. I couldn't find a way to do this better than this:

```
countsegs =
function(g){
    if("LINESTRING" %in% class(g)){
        return(1)
    }
    return(length(g))
}
```

which returns 1 for a line string and the number of linestrings for a multilinestring. We continue:

```
> pli$segs = sapply(pli$geometry, countsegs)
```

Now there's a column with the number of segments in each polygon. Use some `dplyr` package pipes and whatnot to sum over polygon `id` to get a data frame of counts of segments in polygons. There's probably an easier way to strip the geometry out but whatevs:

```
> summed = pli %>% group_by(id) %>%
       summarise(total = sum(segs)) %>% select(id, total)
> summed = as.data.frame(summed)
> summed$geometry=NULL
```

Now join the totals onto the polygon spatial data frame:

```
> polys = left_join(polys, summed, c("id"="id"))
> plot(polys[,"total"])
> plot(lines$geom, add=TRUE)
```

Does this look right?

[image]

Comment: The sf package, in conjuction with packages like dplyr, are really making this type of analyses quite elegant. Thank you for showing an example that is moving us towards this spatial object class. Do you think that it is time to start retooling our packages to use the sf class or is sp still prefered?

Comment: All you need is `sf` and `as(thing,"Spatial")` if you need `sp` classes for packages that work with them.

Comment: Thank you @spacedman. I will try ASAP. I can see that you actually cut each lines for each cells. I hope it can work for a large grid and dataset. We will know soon :)

Comment: thanks again @Spacedman, but it does not work with my sample. Is it possible to have your sample to try out and to do a match with mine?

Comment: @spacedman, it seems to work but the lines are also splitted when they cross each other. For example in the cells in yellow in your results, the value is not 4 but more!

Comment: @Spacedman, I added a sample of the data here: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2w6u1l42txhybsq/AABwBiemNsAmx4WWv6VclPVja?dl=0). After reading the two files as you described, I used `polys$id <- polys$Id` and ´lines$FID <- lines$Id´ to make sure that I have the same parameters than you do. I went throught the steps this morning and I have this issue of the lines crossing - I added a figure in my original post.